# Vue.js - Access component methods on onload

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I use `vue-js` and `stripe` to implement some of my payment.

The only way to use the `Stripe` with `vue-js` was with `script.onload`. I would like now to access some of my `methods` within the `onload` function. In this example it is the function `myMethod` called with `self.myMethod`

To do so I created `self` variable but it happens to be undefined in the scope of `onload`.

How could I do to make it available ?

In the current example `self` refers to `Window` object.

#### Component.vue

```
<template></template>

<script>
export default {
     data() {
         const self = this;
         return {}
     },

     methods: {
         myMethod() {}
     },

     mounted() {
         let script = document.createElement('script');
         script.src = "https://js.stripe.com/v3/";
         script.onload = () => {
             const stripe = Stripe('xxxxxxxx');
             const elements = stripe.elements();

             function setOutcome(result) {
                 self.myMethod();
             }
             card.on('change', function(event) {
                 setOutcome(event);
             });
             document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 const form = document.querySelector('form');
                 stripe.createToken(card).then(setOutcome);
             });
         };
         document.body.appendChild(script);
     }
 }
</script>
<style></style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've defined a `self` variable in the `data` method, which is inaccessible outside of that method.

You need to define the `self` variable within the `mounted` hook itself:

```
mounted() {
  let self = this;
  ...
}
```

Comment: By doing like you said, `self` still refers to `window` and I don't know how to access my method.

Comment: It shouldn't refer to `window` if the exported object is being used in the instantiation of a Vue component. Can you show the code where you are importing this file and using it? Or is this within a `.vue` file?

Comment: This is a component `component.vue`. Sorry I forgot to mention that and I updated the description.

Comment: But you have `<script>` tags around your `export default {}` object right?

Comment: Argh ... Yes, I am sorry again. I'm using `Single File component`. The `self` reference changes when I am in `script.onload = ()`

Comment: Even when you put `let self = this;` as the first line in the `mounted` method?

Comment: I cannot retry right now, but yesterday I did like you suggested and `self` referred to `window`, if I added `self` as a parameter to `onload` then self would refer to `Event`